# Can't get refresh token using passport in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, oauth-2.0, laravel-passport

I tried a lot of things but for now is impossible to me to get the refresh token using api routes. Here is my code. In API.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use GuzzleHttp\Exception\GuzzleException;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\AccessTokenController;

Route::post('connect', function (Request $request) {
$http = new GuzzleHttp\Client;

$response = $http->post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/oauth/token', [
    'form_params' => [
        'grant_type' => 'password',
        'client_id' => $request->client_id,
        'client_secret' => $request->client_secret,
        'username' => $request->username,
        'password' => $request->password,
        'scope' => ''
    ],
]);

return json_decode((string) $response->getBody(), true);
```

});

It always returns the same error:

```
Error creating resource: [message] fopen(http://127.0.0.1:8000/oauth/token): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! [file] /var/www/html/passport_test_3/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/StreamHandler.php
```

[image]
Any help ?

Comment: Can you reach that endpoint using something like, for instance, `postman`?

Comment: no, i can't do that right now

Comment: do you have guzzle installed? Try this to install it `composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle` run it again afterwards and tell us what happened, it is usually pre installed but you could still try it out

Comment: yes i have done that, but i still have the same error

Comment: Who serves the `8000` port? `8005` for laravel?

Comment: My mistake. I finally fixed using a proxy request instead of guzzle

Comment: $response= $user->refresh_token; 
            $request->request->add([
                'grant_type' => 'password',
                'client_id' => $request->client_id,
                'client_secret' => $request->client_secret,
                'username' => $request->email,
                'password' => $request->password,
                'scope' => null
            ]);
        
        // Fire off the internal request. 
        $proxy = Request::create(
            'oauth/token',
            'POST'
        );